# What does “quiet mode” mean for the mkfs command?

Tags: terminology, mkfs

I was reading about the `mkfs` command and I came across something I don't quite understand:

> ## mkfs
>
> ### Syntax
>
> ```
>       mkfs [-t fstype] [fs_options] device
> ```
>
> ### Options :
>
> ............
>
> #### -q
>
> ```
> Uses mkfs in quiet mode, resulting in very little output.
> ```

What is "quiet mode" in the context of filesystem creating ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"quiet" means it won't output anything unless there's an error. If I make a test filesystem with `mkfs` (which just runs `mke2fs` on my system, and probably yours too):

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=test bs=1024 count=1000
1000+0 records in
1000+0 records out
1024000 bytes (1.0 MB) copied, 0.00222076 s, 461 MB/s
$ mkfs test
mke2fs 1.42.10 (18-May-2014)
Discarding device blocks: done                            
Creating filesystem with 1000 1k blocks and 128 inodes

Allocating group tables: done                            
Writing inode tables: done                            
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done
$
```

I get a lot of output. If I do the same thing with `mke2fs -q`:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=test-quiet bs=1024 count=1000
1000+0 records in
1000+0 records out
1024000 bytes (1.0 MB) copied, 0.00222076 s, 461 MB/s
$ mkfs -q test-quiet
$
```

I get no text output. It doesn't affect the created filesystem itself at all, just the terminal output you get while running the command.

(`dd` is making us a 1000KiB file to create the filesystem in, rather than using a real device)

Comment: mkfs not mke2fs !. or it is the same thing for the 2 cmds ? thx u

Comment: mkfs just runs some particular filesystem program by default. It's usually mke2fs, as it is on my system, but they will all have the same behaviour for this flag.